# jquery drag and resize bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, raphael

im stuck resolving an issue.

i want to build a bar chart using raphaeljs or another, the main funccionality is that once drawn, the bars should be resizable by the mouse dragging and be able to get their current value once the drag stopped.
i have tried the bellow code but its not working.

```
        function  drawchart()
        {


            var data  =  [1,2,3];


            /* 
             * Create an instance of raphael and specify:
             * the ID of the div where to insert the graph
             * the width
             * the height
             * Tip: Remember that the reference point (0, 0) is at the top left position.
             */
            var r = Raphael("holder",600,300);


            // start, move, and up are the drag functions
            start = function () {
                // storing original coordinates
                this.ox = this.attr("x");
                this.oy = this.attr("y");
                this.attr({opacity: 1});

                this.sizer.ox = this.sizer.attr("x");
                this.sizer.oy = this.sizer.attr("y");
                this.sizer.attr({opacity: 1});
            },
            move = function (dx, dy) {
                // move will be called with dx and dy
                this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
                this.sizer.attr({x: this.sizer.ox + dx, y: this.sizer.oy + dy});        
            },
            up = function () {
                // restoring state
                this.attr({opacity: .5});
                this.sizer.attr({opacity: .5});        
            },
            rstart = function () {
                // storing original coordinates
                this.ox = this.attr("x");
                this.oy = this.attr("y");

                this.box.ow = this.box.attr("width");
                this.box.oh = this.box.attr("height");        
            },
            rmove = function (dx, dy) {
                // move will be called with dx and dy
                this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
                this.box.attr({width: this.box.ow + dx, height: this.box.oh + dy});
            };   



            var chart = r.g.barchart(5, 5, 200, 280, data, {stacked: false, type: "square"}).label(['a','b','c']);


            chart.drag(move, start, up);


            chart.hover(function() {
                // Create a popup element on top of the bar
                this.flag = r.g.popup(this.bar.x, this.bar.y, (this.bar.value || "0") + "%").insertBefore(this);
            }, function() {
                // hide the popup element with an animation and remove the popup element at the end
                this.flag.animate({opacity: 0}, 300, function () {this.remove();});
            });

            /*
             * Define the default text attributes before writing the labels
             */
            r.g.txtattr = {font:"12px Fontin-Sans, Arial, sans-serif", fill:"#000", "font-weight": "bold"};


            // iterate over all the bar
            for (var i = 0; i < chart.bars[0].length; i++) {
                var bar = chart.bars[0][i];
                // if the value of the bar is greater or equals to 15 we change the color to red
                if (bar.value >= 15) {
                    bar.attr("fill", "#bf2f2f");
                    bar.attr("stroke", "#bf2f2f");
                }
            }

        }
```

any kind of help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can show the HTML/CSS too, and/or throw it up on jfiddle?